# Testcafe reporting own stack

Tags: automation, automated-tests, reporting, e2e-testing, testcafe

I use testcafe and allure reporter in my project. Everything works fine. Now I have written a custom function, that compare XML files. The result is an array with the nodes that are different. Now I want to include this array as stack inside the report. I see that there is a

```
        var errorMsg = {
            name: msgContent.data,
            message: msgContent.message,
            stack: msgContent.stack
        };
```

inside the allure reporter. I can send a own message with the .expect assertion. But how I can send an own stack if an error occur?

Comment: Could you please share more details about your scenario? Will comparison of your nodes array with an empty array `.expect(yourArray).eql([]);` work for you?

Comment: This assertion will just tell you that the array is not [] AssertionError: XML Vergleich fehlgeschlagen: expected [ Array(101) ] to deeply equal [] But I need the Array content inside the stack not the line where it fail.

Answer (score 2):

At present, TestCafe doesn't show difference between objects on assertions. There is a suggestion for this in the TestCafe repository - https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/4785. Track this issue to be informed about the progress.

(**UPDATE**: Implemented in [Adding detailed diffs](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/pull/5255))